# DocuSign REST API : Send customFields for BulkRecipients

Tags: docusignapi, bulk

Is it possible to send customFields for each recipient in case of EnvelopeBulkRecipients when using a csv file ?

Thanks.

Edit :
As a workaround, I will try to update the envelopes after they are sent to the bulk recipients to add the custom field.
Please let me know if you have any other possible workarounds.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like custom fields are not supported for Bulk recipients. Here is another link to the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/sending-envelope-with-bulk-recipient.htm)

Comment: If you have same customfield value for all the recipients then you can add that in the template and then send envelopeBulkReceipient for each recipient using the template.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know this is not mentioned in the documentation but I was hoping for a workaround.

Comment: @Amit actually I need the custom field to be unique per recipient.

Comment: @user8159167: I have a custom HTML based App (not WebApp) which can help in your usecase. It will send the custom field per recipient.

Answer (score 1):

According to the DocuSign API documentation for the [bulkRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/BulkEnvelopes/EnvelopeBulkRecipients/list/#/definitions/bulkRecipient) object, custom fields not supported for bulk recipients.

(On the page I've linked to above: under **Definitions**, click to expand the **bulkRecipient** object, so that all supported properties of **bulkRecipient** are shown.  As you'll see, there is no "customFields" property for the **bulkRecipient** object.)

**Update (potential workaround):**

If you're simply looking to specify a custom metadata for each recipient (like recipient customFields would let you do, if it were supported for bulk recipients), then you might consider doing something like this:

1) when you create the envelope, add an extra text "tab" (field) for the bulk recipient for each of the "custom fields" that you want to track -- and make each of those fields ***hidden***. A "hidden" field is part of the envelope (so you can use the API or .csv file to populate it), but invisible to the recipient.

2) in your bulk recipients file, add a column for each "hidden" field that you created in the envelope, and populate that column to specify a value for each recipient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read the documentation but I was hoping for a workaround. Because this is an important feature in my app.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a potential workaround.  If this meets your needs, can you please mark the answer as "accepted" so that others may benefit from this info in the future?  Thanks!